# moving logo all the way to left

Tags: css, alignment

I have a site I am creating and I just can't seem to get the logo to float ALL the way to the left.

Would some kind soul mind setting me straight (or left as it may be):

this is my site:

seasons. rudtek. com /join-our-team/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be doing the trick:

```
#Top_bar .logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -20px !important;
}
```

Might not be best practice but it's ok.

Comment: Use of !important is frowned upon.  It can cause some pretty big headaches down the road.

Comment: I know, just don't abuse that

Answer (score 1):

In two places, inline and in renew.css you have specified .x-container.width to be 86%. remove this and it works. I suggest familiarizing yourself with the developer tools available in most browsers.

Comment: +1 on the developer tools suggestion.  I'm very loyal to Firefox's Developer Edition but Chrome's tools are nice as well.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is in the css for div.container.  If you remove this rule:

```
.section-wrapper, .container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You'll find the logo moves all the way to the left. That also moves the text on the page to the left as well, though, so you may want to set a different value for the margin for .section-wrapper instead of setting them both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

in style id= mfn-dnmc-style-css 
there is

> Top_bar .logo{float:none;text-align:center;margin:15px 0}

change this to

> .logo{float:**left**;text-align:center;margin:15px 0}

This works.